# How to upload image through multipartform data to server (Android)

Tags: android

I want to upload image to a server. URL:

http://asptest.expenseanywhere.com/eamobile/imageupload.aspx

Server requirer 5 fields for getting the response of successful upload that are: corporate id, username, password, etc. and image also. So how to send all these data to server and upload the image to server successfully? Please reply in details because I am new in Android and Java and I am not getting the idea how to do that. I am reading this article:

http://http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html

but in this article only the image is sent to server. So how to write all the fields which I want to file and send all the fields to server for uploading the image? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this to post form data, it might work for you:

```
    final HttpUriRequest http_request = new HttpPost(url);
    final List<NameValuePair> form_params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    form_params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", value1));                
    form_params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", value2));                
    form_params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key3", value3));                
    try {
        ((HttpPost) http_request).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(form_params));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    http_request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

then use an DefaultHttpClient with this request.

Comment: hello Darrell how can i take image from drawable folder and use it in as key value  pair?pls help

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload it as a byte array. Check out how its done in this blog I found:

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/android-image-upload-activity/

Heres the part your looking for here:

```
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);

            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            entity.addPart("photoId", new StringBody(getIntent()
                    .getStringExtra("photoId")));
           entity.addPart("returnformat", new StringBody("json"));

            entity.addPart("uploaded", new ByteArrayBody(data,
                    "myImage.jpg"));
            entity.addPart("photoCaption", new StringBody(caption.getText()
                    .toString()));
```